# litespeed issue with content-type

Tags: litespeed

I am running magento with litespeed.

The problem I am facing is that ajax call is being made of which header is set as x-json, but lightspeed is setting another header of text/html content type

I've checked that page with apache and everything is working fine.

I checked the response headers with apache and litespeed and here are they:

With apache:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2012 05:58:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: frontend=164b21c64808a05e806027bdbd4d745d; expires=Fri, 07-Sep-2012 06:58:48 GMT; path=/; domain=mydomain.com; httponly
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-json

With litespeed:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2012 06:10:55 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: frontend=164b21c64808a05e806027bdbd4d745d; expires=Fri, 07-Sep-2012 07:10:55 GMT; path=/; domain=mydomain.com; httponly
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 474
Vary: User-Agent

I've also added application/json to mime.properties of litespeed,restarted it but that did not work.

Here is the screenshot
[image]